# How render js plugins to backend of Gutenberg Editor

Tags: wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I have a question about Gutenberg Editor in Wordpress.
I have a button block with some content and I want to make some scripts on click.
So I npm gsap plugin to script.js file, which is registered like 'script'.
Added some js and everything is working fine in frontend, but not in backend.
I registered my scripts like that:

```
wp_register_script( 'my-blocks-script', plugins_url('dist/script.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true );
```

and tried to register like that:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'my-blocks-script', plugins_url('dist/script.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true);
```

And nothing, only working in frontend. I tried different js plugins, but they all work only in frontend. There is no any error in console. Can you give me advice, what should I do?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I forgot that I should import react type npm js packages.